# ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: vb.net, oledbconnection

I'm getting the following error

> ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

When the following code is run

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    Using con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\Comp-296\Project1\Project1\Game_time.mdb")

        Using cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE User-scores SET User_Name = @User_Name Game_Name = @Game_Name Score = @Score, [Time/Date] = @dt")

            con.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_Name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtUser.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Game_Name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtGame.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Score", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtScore.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt", OleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MessageBox.Show("Data Update successfully")
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Did I forget to put something in the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the connection as a parameter to the `OledbCommand`

Just use the following code

```
Using con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\Comp-296\Project1\Project1\Game_time.mdb") 

    Using cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [User-scores] SET [User_Name] = ?, [Game_Name] = ?, Score = ?, [Time/Date] = ? WHERE id = 1", con) 
        con.Open() 
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtUser.Text 
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtGame.Text 
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtScore.Text 
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p4", OleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text) 

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 

        MessageBox.Show("Data Update successfully") 
    End Using 
End Using
```

It look like you have to use `?` mark to pass parameter to an `OledbCommand` *(your method is for `SQLCommand`)*

Read more about [Oledb Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank u It work now im getting Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

Comment: @FrankLobgo you missed to add commas between columns. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add connection to command, Update cmd , add con like below

```
 Using cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE User-scores SET User_Name = @User_Name Game_Name = @Game_Name Score = @Score, [Time/Date] = @dt",con)
```

**Update** : MISSING COMMA IN UPDATE

```
 @User_Name, Game_Name = @Game_NamE, Score = @Score
```

Comment: Thank u It work now im getting Syntax error in UPDATE statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141837/discussion-between-tushar-and-frank-longo).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't associated the Command with the Connection. The code doesn't know which connection (in theory you could have several) to run the command against.

You can associate a command with a particular connection in two different ways - using the constructor, or the property:

```
Using cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE User-scores SET User_Name = @User_Name Game_Name = @Game_Name Score = @Score, [Time/Date] = @dt",con)
```

Or:

```
cmd.Connection = con
```

(on the line after you declare `cmd`)

Comment: Thank u It work now im getting Syntax error in UPDATE statement

Comment: you missed out two commas between the fields: `User_Name = @User_Name Game_Name = @Game_Name Score = @Score` should be `User_Name = @User_Name, Game_Name = @Game_Name, Score = @Score`

Answer (score 0):

You can have the connect create the command with [CreateCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.createcommand(v=vs.110).aspx). That way the connection will already be associated with the created command. This means though, that you would have to set the command text on the `CommandText` property

```
Using con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\Comp-296\Project1\Project1\Game_time.mdb")

    Using cmd = con.CreateCommand()
        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE User-scores SET User_Name = @User_Name, Game_Name = @Game_Name, Score = @Score, [Time/Date] = @dt"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_Name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtUser.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Game_Name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtGame.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Score", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtScore.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dt", OleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


        MessageBox.Show("Data Update successfully")
    End Using
End Using
```